# Mistake in Python Queue Peek

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to implement a Queue peek that blocks on an empty `self.queue` in a class:

```
        def peek(self):
            while self.queue.empty():
                self.queue.not_empty.wait()
            queue_data = self.queue.queue
            return queue_data[0]
```

This gets called in a  thread, but when I call `join()` on the thread the `wait()` seems to give up on waiting and does not return data.  Is this the wrong way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by extending Queue to PeekQueue and adding a peek() method.  I copied the code from Queue's get() method and replaced to call to _get at the end with an indexed removal from the dequeue.

A better solution might be to pass the queue operation to a function that handles all the timing.

```
class PeekQueue(Queue):
    def peek(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        '''Return first item from queue without removing it

        If optional args 'block' is true and 'timeout' is None (the default),
        block if necessary until an item is available. If 'timeout' is
        a non-negative number, it blocks at most 'timeout' seconds and raises
        the Empty exception if no item was available within that time.
        Otherwise ('block' is false), return an item if one is immediately
        available, else raise the Empty exception ('timeout' is ignored
        in that case).
        '''
        with self.not_empty:
            if not block:
                if not self._qsize():
                    raise Empty
            elif timeout is None:
                while not self._qsize():
                    self.not_empty.wait()
            elif timeout < 0:
                raise ValueError("'timeout' must be a non-negative number")
            else:
                endtime = time() + timeout
                while not self._qsize():
                    remaining = endtime - time()
                    if remaining <= 0.0:
                        raise Empty
                    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
            item = self.queue[0]     #<----------- THE ONLY CHANGE from get()
            self.not_full.notify()
            return item
```

Comment: Why did you leave the `self.not_full.notify()` in place in `peek()`?  It doesn't make sense to me to notify threads that are waiting to `put()` into a full queue if you haven't removed an item from the queue.

Comment: Good point.  It is a classic copy/paste bug.